# What are the locations and level requirements for each of the dungeons?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So far I've managed to make it fairly far through the main story with decent map completion without ever entering a dungeon, but while reading through all of the mails I've collected for completing various renowned and personal story quests I have noticed I've been collecting a variety of mails whose icon is a 'door' - I am assuming that these are dungeons.

Looking at the map I have noticed I have a couple of these appearing in relation to the mails, which I am assuming are dungeon entrances:

[image: door]

What are the locations and level requirements for each of the dungeons? Do all of the dungeons follow on from a specific part of the story, and are these affected by the choices I make during my personal story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dungeon#List_of_dungeons) contains the list of dungeons, their locations, and their requirements:

[image: dungeon list]

Comment: *The lack of a proper formatting tool made me give up quoting the list from the link. No tables here, and the bulleted lists are getting too messed up for clarity. As such, the best I can do is a screenshot. Pity for the links.*

Comment: Thanks - I should probably start checking this wiki more, but the link provided does lead me on to [another question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/95001/27134) - how can you get 43 experiences out of 9 dungeons?

Comment: The wiki is fantastic and can even be accessed in game by typing /wiki (it'll bring up the wiki in your default browser)

Comment: @Gwen thanks for the tip on that, I was completely unaware

Comment: Dungeons have a story mode and some explorable modes each, with different paths. That's how you can get multiple experiences with fewer dungeons!